Can I demolish concrete block walls in the basement under concrete beams?
I've recently bought a house with a spacious basement. The basement has several walls that divide it into "sections" with free passage between them. I'd like to demolish some of the walls. Upon inspection they were build just to divide the space, not to work as support. The ceiling looks (photos) to be well supported by concrete girders (entire basement).
I'm looking for an opinion if it's safe to do it or it's better to consult a structural engineer before.
Wall in question:

Reinforced (rebars visible in one or two of them) girders:

Top view of the basement with central supporting wall for the girders:


This is a horse of a different color when it comes to the plethora of load-bearing wall questions we see, but the answer is the same: No one on the internet will be able to give you absolute confidence. Get a local expert on scene and don't rely on "an opinion" for your safety and the preservation of your investment.
